# Populate JSON with javascript array and modify entry

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Modifying a JSON array (nested into another array) seems NOK with this code:

```
   var names = [{'name': 'ourname'},{'name': 'yourname'}] ;

    var array = [{
        "year": "2015",
        names
      },{
        "year": "2016",
         names
      }];
```

I can't modify a single name entry in "array" by doing this

```
array[0].names[1].name="MY NAME"
```

since it's actually modifying all names entry in the row "0":

Output:

```
0:0 ourname
0:1 MY NAME
1:0 ourname
1:1 MY NAME
```

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vhnVFP9RHF1aEX7Av7Bw?p=preview)

I'm looking for a clean way to achieve a proper single modification in the name array as I'd like to avoid loops to do this.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Because they're pointing to same array, and also, simply clone `names` by `.slice` is not enough, as the array contains `objects` not primitive types, so you need to deep clone from the original `names` and assign to each object.
So you need to change the code to :

```
var array = [{
  "year": "2015",
  names: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(names))
}, {
  "year": "2016",
  names: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(names))
}];
```

See the edited [pluker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UceUBb1Qn3hAs1LOlRSh?p=preview).

I use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(names))` to simply create do deep clone from original array here, there can have other ways.

Comment: No problem, and note that JSON.parse(JSON.stringify) is easy to use if the object is not very deep, and small. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object) is good if you want to find more about deep clone.

Answer (score 0):

You should try copying the names array, once for each "unique" use case, since Javascript sneakily has references sometimes.

One way to do it is to write a `deepclone()` method that will do a deep copy of a hierarchical object.

```
var array = [{
    "year": "2015",
    names: deepclone(names)
},{
    "year": "2016",
    names: deepclone(names)
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a key: value in an object (javascript object).

```
var names = [{'name': 'ourname'},{'name': 'yourname'}] ;

var array = [{
        "year": "2015",
        "names": names
      },{
        "year": "2016",
        "names": names
      }];
var wName = array[0].names[1].name;
// yourname
```